# how to use filter with multiple condition in a same data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny App where a user selects a gene and see the table and plot associated with it.

currently I am trying to add one more feature, 
where user selects a module  , then the user will get to see a data table which I have attached here ,

my question is  about when I am trying, to plot this user selected data in a heatmap but when I plot it with the help of following code it doesn't know which location to choose

Here I can use max & abs function to choose a loacation which have highest values.

Example : gene_name ABC have 3 location then it should compare those three location and show a location which has the maximum value

link to table -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAwMk.png

```
   #server.r code
   buildPlot969 <- reactive({

   abcd=data_user()#    here this function have the user selected module data
                   #   plot code chunk                            

   h2=Heatmap(reshape2::dcast(abcd,Gene_name~sample_Id,value.var="values")
   %>% data.frame(.,row.names = "Gene_name")
   %>% apply(.,1function(x)(x-mean(x))/sd(x)),
            fun.aggregate=function(x){x[which.max(abs(x))]})

                           })      

   output$heat_cell1 <- renderPlot(
                           {
                     buildPlot969()
                   },
                   height = 700
                 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            abcd=data_user()
            abcd_1<-as.data.frame(unite(abcd,GENE_NAME_ID,Gene_name,sample_id,remove = FALSE)) # first unite two columns of that data frame to get that value 


            test<-as.character(unique(abcd_1$GENE_NAME_ID)) # get the unique gene name id 


           # using sapply function inside that colMaxs from fBasics package which can look 
             into all columns and get the maximum value 

            Masx_gene_value<-sapply(test,function(x) colMaxs(abcd_1$atac_log_fc[grep(x, test)])) 

             # got the max values saved it in "Masx_gene_value"

            # converted it into data frame 
            Masx_gene_value<-as.data.frame(Masx_gene_value)
            Masx_gene_value$GENE_ID<-rownames(Masx_gene_value)
            rownames(Masx_gene_value)<-NULL
            Masx_gene_value$GENE_ID<-sub("_","@",Masx_gene_value$GENE_ID)
            abcd_2<-as.data.frame(Masx_gene_value %>% separate(GENE_ID,c("Gene_name","ID"),sep = "@"))



            #removed some unwanted data from top and used it in map 
            h1=Heatmap(reshape2::dcast(abcd_2,Gene_name~ID,value.var="Masx_gene_value") %>% data.frame(.,row.names = "Gene_name") %>% apply(.,1,function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)) %>% t())
            draw(h1)
```